# How to give subfolder path to boto.client.file_download?

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I am using boto3 to download files from s3 bucket into local system.
The problem I am facing is with the subfolders. I am not able to pass the path of the folder.

The file gets downloaded correctly if the file is under the bucket, but for all other files in sub-folders I get the below error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

Folder Structure:

```
S3-bucket
   ||
    ==> Sub-Folder
```

My code:

```
    aws_f_name = 'text_file.txt'
    aws_f_dir = '/testdir'
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-west-2')
    s3_client.download_file('womply-data-science','%s/%s' %(aws_f_name, aws_f_dir),'my_locat_file.txt')
```

Any inputs / help would be greatly appreciated on how to give the sub-folder paths. The documentation for boto is [here.](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "folders" in S3. What you see is just a visual representation of folders. You simply have to make sure that the key you are entering is correct. But your error here seems to be because you are writing filename/foldername instead of foldername/filename

The %s notation is outdated, I would recommend you use the format method or simply the `+` syntax like:

```
s3_client.download_file('womply-data-science','{0}/{1}'.format(aws_f_dir, aws_f_name),'my_locat_file.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

the link you provided is a link to an example and not to the actual documentation. The link to the actual Documentation of the function download_file is [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file).

In your case the correct function call is:

```py
s3_client.download_file('womply-data-science', 'test_dir/text_file.txt', 'my_local_file.txt')
```